# how to select all table rows

Tags: jquery

I have a table which contain more than 700 rows which its data shown in a grid and in a different pages so that each page include 20 rows. I need a button in the first page so that whenever it click all 700 rows select.
There is a check box in each row and I wanna they checked all when user click the button.
For handle it I put a button in page so that when user click it all rows check.

```
$("#selectallboxes").click ( function () {
         $('#userTable input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    })
```

HTML code:

```
<input type='button' value='select all rows' id='selectallboxes' name='selectallboxes' />
```

Comment: In general, it's bad UI design to allow the user to interact with elements that are not currently displayed. The normal user expectation will be that a "Select All" button will select all elements (table rows) on the current page. If you do otherwise, then proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#userTable input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: My friends, Actually I wanna select all row in a table which show through the grid in a page. I think I need a query on this table which select all rows in my code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#selectallboxes").click ( function () {
         $('#userTable input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
    })
```

**EDIT**

If you want to check in all pages then

1. You will have create a cookie and when button is clicked then set this true else false.
2. Then check for the cookie is true or false then using jQuery check all the checkbox.

This way you can do that..!

Comment: My own code works but it checks just all rows in the first page. I need a code which check all rows in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery higher than 1.6+ then you need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

jQuery differentiates between attributes and properties.

1. .attr() gets you attributes,
2. .prop() gets your properties.

If you use .attr() it will return true whether the checkbox is checked or not, as it is simply telling you that a checked property exists. So `checked="false"` will actually return true if you use .attr(). If you use .prop() it will return false. .attr() WILL work if you have no checked attr at all, but it will only work the first time you use it! All subsequent calls to .attr("checked") will indicate true.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply apply a class to all check boxes

```
$('.className').attr('checked','true')
```